# Return maximum list of list in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, max

I have these two classes :

```
public class Result
{
    public string plate { get; set; }
    public double confidence { get; set; }
    public int matches_template { get; set; }
    public int plate_index { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public int region_confidence { get; set; }
    public long processing_time_ms { get; set; }
    public int requested_topn { get; set; }
    public List<Coordinate> coordinates { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> candidates { get; set; }
}

public class Candidate
{
    public string plate { get; set; }
    public double confidence { get; set; }
    public int matches_template { get; set; }
}
```

I have this query :

```
List<List<Candidate>> lstCandidates =
                    deserializedProduct.results.Select(i=>i.candidates).ToList();
```

As you can see I have a list of `list<Candidate>`. Every candidate has `plate` and `confidence`. I need the plate number with maximum confidence in my `lstCandidates`. How can get this value?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I will be happy to help but you must show what you have tried so we can help you correct it. Also are you looking for the max `confidence` value or are you looking for the `Candidate` item that has the max `confidence` value.

Comment: @GiladGreen You know i want to use foreach solution ,traditional solution .But not code yet .I want to know maybe there is a better solution

Comment: @GiladGreen  I need the plate number with maximum confidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` then `OrderBy` and use `First` methods.

```
var candidate = deserializedProduct
                    .results
                    .SelectMany(i=>i.candidates) // Flatten the collection
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.confidence) // Order by descending on confidence property 
                    .First(); // Take the max
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten the inner lists, then order the items by the `confidence` value and retrieve the first value.

```
var result = deserializedProduct.results.SelectMany(item => item.candidates) //Flatten
                                        .OrderByDescending(item => item.confidence) //Order
                                        .FirstOrDefault()?.plate; // Safely take property of first
```

*The `?.` is C# 6.0 Null propagation feature*

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's very simple

```
deserializedProduct.results
    .SelectMany(k => k.candidates)
    .OrderByDescending(k => k.confidence) 
    .Select(k=>k.plate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @EhsanAkbar In what collection do you apply the list? See my edit then.